# Resolve Math Functions PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, math, plsql

I need to resolve a math equation/function in pl/sql.
What kind of math operations/functions are available in oracle pl/sql that could help me resolve a math function like this :

`(3.5/(1+x))+(3.5/(1+x)^2)+(3.5/(1+x)^3)+(3.5/(1+x)^4)+(100/(1+x)^4)=101.55`

I want a function to resolve this statement and find out the value of `x`.

[Something like this is what I am looking for](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283.5%2F%281%2Bx%29%29%2B%283.5%2F%281%2Bx%29%5E2%29%2B%283.5%2F%281%2Bx%29%5E3%29%2B%283.5%2F%281%2Bx%29%5E4%29%2B%28100%2F%281%2Bx%29%5E4%29%3D101.55)

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I presume, since you're using SQL, that the database will supply the value for `x`, is that correct?

Comment: No, actually I mean to find out what is the value of x xD

Comment: if its not a built in function, you'd either use brute force or write some custom function.  Depending on what you want to do, I would look into using Mathematica ( http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica )

Comment: As your variable x is raised to the power 4 there will be 4 different values for x, right?

Comment: Have you tried Taylor's series?

Comment: tSQL was not ment to solve this kind of problems. Yes, maybe you can do it, but is not inteded for that.

Comment: You could have PL/SQL use the [WolframAlpha API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/explorer.html).  But requesting, receiving, and parsing the results would probably be very slow.  How many equations do you have?

Comment: @jonearles atm I got only this one, but if this worked maybe would try new ones

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alas the Oracle database is not a mathematical tool.  It has lots of [arithmetical and statistical functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions002.htm#CJAIBHGG) but it doesn't have built-in functionality capable of interpreting equations.  Sorry.

---

By sheer coincidence Marc (AKA [Odie_63](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/profile.jspa?userID=695787)) has recently published a Reverse Polish Notation calculator which he has written in PL/SQL.  It doesn't do precisely what you want but I'm including a link for the benefit of any seekers who may stumble upon this thread in the future.  [Find out more.](http://odieweblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/plsql-rpn-calculator/)

Answer (score 4):

As APC said, there is no built-in functionality to do this.  But you can use the [WolframAlpha API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/explorer.html) from PL/SQL:

```
declare
    v_equation varchar2(32767) := 
        '(3.5/(1+x))+(3.5/(1+x)^2)+(3.5/(1+x)^3)+(3.5/(1+x)^4)+(100/(1+x)^4)=101.55';
    v_escaped_url varchar2(32767);
    v_uri httpuritype;
    v_xml xmltype;
    v_count number := 1;
begin
    --Escape the URL.
    --I used chr(38) for ampersand, in case your IDE think it's a substitution variable
    v_escaped_url :=
        'http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?appid=EQGHLV-UYUEYY9ARU'||chr(38)||'input='
        ||utl_url.escape(v_equation, escape_reserved_chars => true)
        ||chr(38)||'format=plaintext';

    --Create an HTTPURIType, and get the XML
    v_uri := httpuritype.createUri(v_escaped_url);
    v_xml := v_uri.getXML;

    --Complex solutions
    while v_xml.existsNode('/queryresult/pod[@title="Complex solutions"]/subpod['||v_count||']') = 1 loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_xml.extract('/queryresult/pod[@title="Complex solutions"]/subpod['||v_count||']/plaintext/text()').getStringVal());
        v_count := v_count + 1;
    end loop;

    --Real solutions
    v_count := 1;
    while v_xml.existsNode('/queryresult/pod[@title="Real solutions"]/subpod['||v_count||']') = 1 loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_xml.extract('/queryresult/pod[@title="Real solutions"]/subpod['||v_count||']/plaintext/text()').getStringVal());
        v_count := v_count + 1;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Results:

```
x = -1.00006-0.996229 i
x = -1.00006+0.996229 i
x = -1.99623
x = 0.0308219
```

There are a lot of potential downsides to this approach.  It will be very slow, and the API is not free.  My example works because I used my free developer appid, but it's only good for a small number of calls.

Comment: Sorry but but i'm looking for a "standalone" approach

Comment: +1 This is a party trick, and a neat one at that.  But many production systems would not allow the database to connect to another site like this. Also your application becomes dependent on a third party's availability.  Of course many enterprise systems are built of web services these days, but very rarely calling them from the database.